# Sticky Bit in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, file-permissions, hdfs, sticky

I am using Apache Hadoop (hadoop-0.20.203.0) and unable to set sticky bit for /tmp directory in hdfs. My intention is to set it's permission as 1777.

```
$hadoop dfs -chmod 1777 /tmp
chmod: chmod : mode '1777' does not match the expected pattern.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 1777 /tmp
```

worked for me with hadoop(0.20.2-cdh3u2)

Comment: I switched to 0.20.2-cdh3u2. Thanks!
Let me know if there is a good patch for Apache Hadoop (hadoop-0.20.203.0)

Answer (score 1):

Sticky bit doesn't show up in Apache until 0.21, which isn't a stable release, so more realistically, in the 2.0 branch.  The fact that it was committed to trunk in January 2009 says loads about the long road the project's been on.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the mode as a letter instead of as octal:

```
hadoop dfs -chmod +t /tmp
```

Edit: For the record, 1777 (your example) worked fine for me (0.20.2-cdh3u2).